# rake db:migrate not working on my postgres db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

Ok so i have a rails application that I am attempting to run the migrations on a postgres db and I usually use mysql and all is good but when i run the command i get this

```
rake db:migrate
(in /Users/tamer/Sites/my_app)
/Users/tamer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@my_app/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:487: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0]

-- control frame ----------
c:0058 p:---- s:0215 b:0215 l:000214 d:000214 CFUNC  :exec
c:0057 p:0040 s:0211 b:0211 l:000191 d:000210 BLOCK  /Users/tamer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@my_app/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter
c:0056 p:0005 s:0208 b:0208 l:000198 d:000207 BLOCK  /Users/tamer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@my_app/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.r
c:0055 p:0032 s:0206 b:0206 l:000205 d:000205 METHOD /Users/tamer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@my_app/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21
c:0054 p:0052 s:0199 b:0199 l:000198 d:000198 METHOD /Users/tamer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@my_app/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.r
c:0053 p:0018 s:0192 b:0192 l:000191 d:000191 METHOD /Users/tamer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@my_app/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter
c:0052 p:0013 s:0187 b:0187 l:000186 d:000186 METHOD /Users/tamer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@my_app/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter
c:0051 p:0011 s:0184 b:0184 l:000183 d:000183 METHOD /Users/tamer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@my_app/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter
c:0050 p:0136 s:0180 b:0180 l:000179 d:000179 METHOD /Users/tamer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@my_app/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter
c:0049 p:0131 s:0177 b:0177 l:000176 d:000176 METHOD /Users/tamer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@my_app/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter
c:0048 p:0054 s:0174 b:0174 l:000173 d:000173 METHOD /Users/tamer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@my_app/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter
c:0047 p:---- s:0167 b:0167 l:000166 d:000166 FINISH
c:0046 p:---- s:0165 b:0165 l:000164 d:000164 CFUNC  :new
c:0045 p:0186 s:0158 b:0158 l:000157 d:000157 METHOD /Users/tamer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@my_app/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter
c:0044 p:0045 s:0149 b:0149 l:000148 d:000148 METHOD /Users/tamer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@my_app/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connectio
c:0043 p:0011 s:0146 b:0146 l:000145 d:000145 METHOD /Users/tamer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@my_app/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connectio
c:0042 p:0048 s:0142 b:0142 l:000128 d:000141 BLOCK  /Users/tamer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@my_app/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connectio
c:0041 p:---- s:0139 b:0139 l:000138 d:000138 FINISH
c:0040 p:---- s:0137 b:0137 l:000136 d:000136 CFUNC  :loop
c:0039 p:0009 s:0134 b:0134 l:000128 d:000133 BLOCK  /Users/tamer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@my_app/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connectio
c:0038 p:0019 s:0132 b:0132 l:000131 d:000131 METHOD /Users/tamer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201
c:0037 p:0013 s:0129 b:0129 l:000128 d:000128 METHOD /Users/tamer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@my_app/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connectio
c:0036 p:0030 s:0126 b:0123 l:000122 d:000122 METHOD /Users/tamer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@my_app/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connectio
c:0035 p:0033 s:0120 b:0120 l:000119 d:000119 METHOD /Users/tamer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@my_app/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connectio
c:0034 p:0018 s:0115 b:0115 l:000114 d:000114 METHOD /Users/tamer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@my_app/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connectio
c:0033 p:0011 s:0112 b:0112 l:000111 d:000111 METHOD /Users/tamer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@my_app/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connectio
c:0032 p:0020 s:0109 b:0109 l:000108 d:000108 METHOD /Users/tamer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@my_app/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:486
c:0031 p:---- s:0103 b:0103 l:000102 d:000102 FINISH
c:0030 p:---- s:0101 b:0101 l:000100 d:000100 CFUNC  :new
c:0029 p:0020 s:0095 b:0095 l:000094 d:000094 METHOD /Users/tamer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@my_app/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:433
c:0028 p:0083 s:0090 b:0090 l:000089 d:000089 METHOD /Users/tamer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@my_app/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:415
c:0027 p:0102 s:0085 b:0085 l:000d58 d:000084 BLOCK  /Users/tamer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@my_app/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:142
c:0026 p:---- s:0083 b:0083 l:000082 d:000082 FINISH
c:0025 p:---- s:0081 b:0081 l:000080 d:000080 CFUNC  :call
c:0024 p:0043 s:0076 b:0076 l:000067 d:000075 BLOCK  /Users/tamer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@my_app/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636
c:0023 p:---- s:0073 b:0073 l:000072 d:000072 FINISH
c:0022 p:---- s:0071 b:0071 l:000070 d:000070 CFUNC  :each
c:0021 p:0171 s:0068 b:0068 l:000067 d:000067 METHOD /Users/tamer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@my_app/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631
c:0020 p:0110 s:0064 b:0064 l:000058 d:000063 BLOCK  /Users/tamer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@my_app/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:597
c:0019 p:0019 s:0062 b:0062 l:000061 d:000061 METHOD /Users/tamer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201
c:0018 p:0033 s:0059 b:0059 l:000058 d:000058 METHOD /Users/tamer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@my_app/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590
c:0017 p:0048 s:0053 b:0053 l:000052 d:000052 METHOD /Users/tamer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@my_app/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:583
c:0016 p:0045 s:0048 b:0048 l:000047 d:000047 METHOD /Users/tamer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@my_app/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2051
c:0015 p:0012 s:0041 b:0041 l:000026 d:000040 BLOCK  /Users/tamer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@my_app/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029
c:0014 p:---- s:0038 b:0038 l:000037 d:000037 FINISH
c:0013 p:---- s:0036 b:0036 l:000035 d:000035 CFUNC  :each
c:0012 p:0069 s:0033 b:0033 l:000026 d:000032 BLOCK  /Users/tamer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@my_app/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029
c:0011 p:0009 s:0031 b:0031 l:000030 d:000030 METHOD /Users/tamer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@my_app/gems/airbrake-3.0.9/lib/airbrake/rake_handler.rb:33
c:0010 p:0011 s:0027 b:0027 l:000026 d:000026 METHOD /Users/tamer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@my_app/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2023
c:0009 p:0029 s:0024 b:0024 l:000017 d:000023 BLOCK  /Users/tamer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@my_app/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2001
c:0008 p:0009 s:0022 b:0022 l:000021 d:000021 METHOD /Users/tamer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@my_app/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068
c:0007 p:0011 s:0018 b:0018 l:000017 d:000017 METHOD /Users/tamer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@my_app/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1998
c:0006 p:0036 s:0015 b:0015 l:000014 d:000014 TOP    /Users/tamer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@my_app/gems/rake-0.8.7/bin/rake:31
c:0005 p:---- s:0013 b:0013 l:000012 d:000012 FINISH
c:0004 p:---- s:0011 b:0011 l:000010 d:000010 CFUNC  :load
c:0003 p:0127 s:0007 b:0007 l:0014e8 d:000f40 EVAL   /Users/tamer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@my_app/bin/rake:19
c:0002 p:---- s:0004 b:0004 l:000003 d:000003 FINISH
c:0001 p:0000 s:0002 b:0002 l:0014e8 d:0014e8 TOP   
---------------------------
-- Ruby level backtrace information ----------------------------------------
/Users/tamer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@my_app/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
/Users/tamer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@my_app/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/Users/tamer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@my_app/gems/rake-0.8.7/bin/rake:31:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/tamer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@my_app/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1998:in `run'
/Users/tamer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@my_app/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/tamer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@my_app/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2001:in `block in run'
/Users/tamer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@my_app/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2023:in `top_level'
/Users/tamer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@my_app/gems/airbrake-3.0.9/lib/airbrake/rake_handler.rb:33:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/tamer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@my_app/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `block in top_level'
/Users/tamer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@my_app/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `each'
/Users/tamer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@my_app/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/tamer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@my_app/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2051:in `invoke_task'
/Users/tamer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@my_app/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:583:in `invoke'
/Users/tamer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@my_app/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/tamer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/tamer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@my_app/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:597:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/tamer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@my_app/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `execute'
/Users/tamer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@my_app/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `each'
/Users/tamer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@my_app/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `block in execute'
/Users/tamer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@my_app/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `call'
/Users/tamer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@my_app/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:142:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/tamer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@my_app/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:415:in `migrate'
/Users/tamer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@my_app/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:433:in `up'
/Users/tamer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@my_app/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:433:in `new'
/Users/tamer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@my_app/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:486:in `initialize'
/Users/tamer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@my_app/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:89:in `connection'
/Users/tamer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@my_app/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:97:in `retrieve_connection'
/Users/tamer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@my_app/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:316:in `retrieve_connection'
/Users/tamer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@my_app/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:93:in `connection'
/Users/tamer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@my_app/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:185:in `checkout'
/Users/tamer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/tamer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@my_app/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:186:in `block in checkout'
/Users/tamer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@my_app/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:186:in `loop'
/Users/tamer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@my_app/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:190:in `block (2 levels) in checkout'
/Users/tamer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@my_app/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:236:in `checkout_new_connection'
/Users/tamer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@my_app/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:228:in `new_connection'
/Users/tamer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@my_app/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:25:in `postgresql_connection'
/Users/tamer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@my_app/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:25:in `new'
/Users/tamer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@my_app/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:228:in `initialize'
/Users/tamer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@my_app/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:939:in `connect'
/Users/tamer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@my_app/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:956:in `configure_connection'
/Users/tamer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@my_app/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:278:in `set_standard_conforming_strings'
/Users/tamer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@my_app/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:699:in `client_min_messages'
/Users/tamer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@my_app/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:483:in `query'
/Users/tamer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@my_app/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:195:in `log'
/Users/tamer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@my_app/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
/Users/tamer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@my_app/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:197:in `block in log'
/Users/tamer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@my_app/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:487:in `block in query'
/Users/tamer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@my_app/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:487:in `exec'

-- C level backtrace information -------------------------------------------

[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html

Abort trap
```

My database.yml file looks like this

```
development: 
encoding: unicode
adapter: postgresql
username: postgres
port: 5432
host: localhost
database: test
password: password
```

Any idea what i am doing wrong..these are the correct credentials because i conntect to this postgres db with a GUI tool with these creds

I used this [link](http://excid3.com/blog/installing-postgresql-and-pg-gem-on-mac-osx/) to install the pg gem

Comment: Same problem if you run?

    $bundle exec rake db:migrate

Comment: I just got this exact same problem. However: Linux, ruby 1.9.3p0, and AR 3.2.1

Answer (score 3):

Given that you got an actual segmentation fault, I'd bet on a problem with your pg gem in conjunction with libpg.  Did you by any chance upgrade your OS lately?

If this seems like a reasonable thing, you might try saving a backup of your database, nuking your existing pg installation (database, libraries and gems), then reinstalling it all in hopes of getting rid of whatever incompatibilities are causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have mysql and postgresql database in the same application. Here are the steps which i have followed to set up the postgresql database.

1. Install PostgreSQL and its libraries
   `sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib libpq-dev`
2. After the installation create a user for postgresql
   `sudo -u postgres createuser --superuser $USER`
    or
   `sudo -u postgres createuser pgs_root`
3. Set user password for the postgresql user
   `sudo -u postgres psql postgres ( For psql prompt)`
   `postgres=# \password <user>`
   for ex.- `postgres=# \passsword pgs_root`
4. Configure the postgresql.conf file to make PostgreSQL listen to localhost or listen on an external IP or something, change this line to either the IP or 'localhost'
   **gedit /etc/postgresql/8.4/main/postgresql.conf**
   `listen_addresses = 'localhost'`
5. In order for your application to connect with database present in PostgreSQL, configure it in the database.yml

   `development_postgres:
           adapter: postgresql
           database: connect_postgres
           username: pgs_root
           password: root123
           host: 127.0.0.1`
6. `rake db:create RAILS_ENV=development_postgres`

Like mysql query browser, there is a GUI for postgresql called pgadmin. To install

```
sudo apt-get install pgadmin3
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try the following:

1. remove the host line
2. run bundle update
3. rename the database, just to make sure its fresh
4. run rake db:create
5. run rake db:migrate

I have had issues where my pg gem is not the right version for my version of rails

Answer (score 0):

update all gems using Bundle Update command then run bundle exec rake db:migrate, It works for me.

best luck

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and tried almost every solution on internet with no results.

**But I finally found the solution.**

The answer is to nuke (reinstall) everything.
That means:

- resinstall PostgreSQL and its libraries (`postgresql-9.1 postgresql-client postgresql-client-9.1 postgresql-client-common postgresql-common postgresql-contrib postgresql-contrib-9.1 postgresql-server-dev-9.1  libpgsql-ruby libpq-dev` etc)
- delete totally and create Ruby gemsets (the one which is bugged)
- Reinstall Ruby eg. `rvm reinstall 1.9.3` (this is very important, without that step it wont work)
- If you have obsolete libraries (`libpgsql-ruby1.8` etc) delete them.

PS This problem appeared in my machine when I upgrade Debian (from Squeeze to Wheezy).

**Edit:**

More explanation for this error:

https://bitbucket.org/ged/ruby-pg/issue/76/segfault-on-ruby-18-and-ruby-19-using#comment-590323

Answer (score 0):

sometimes it is caused by a clash between multiple libssl versions

try that:

- apt-get remove libssl0.9.8
- rvm reinstall default